# How to append L to long in Java

Tags: java, android, long-integer

I have this long 1383903835525 but need to append L for Java to recognize it as a long otherwise I get the 'int is too long' error

So the en result will be **1383903835525L**

---

Im trying to date.getDate(1383903835525);

```
public String getDate(long milliseconds) {
        setDateFormat();
        return getResult(milliseconds);
    }
```

this works

> date.getDate(1383903835525L);

but the server is sending me back this in the response 1383903835525
Should the server rather send back 1383903835525L ?

Comment: The **only** place where Java needs the `L` is in *source code* and there you add it by *typing it*. What exactly are you asking about?

Comment: _"int is too long"_ Funny.

Comment: Im trying to pass in 1383731967037 into a method that returns a formatted date, when I pass in 1383731967037 'Integer number too large' when I pass in 1383731967037L it works fine, how do I add the L?

Comment: @Francois: you said it yourself: "when I pass in 1383731967037L it works fine". **Do that!** If that's not the solution, then you **must** show us your code.

Comment: @Francois it would be easy to understand your problem , if you paste the code you are trying.

Comment: And what do you **do** with the data the server sent you?

Answer (score 4):

If the server response is a string, you can convert it to a long by calling Long.parseLong(string).

```
Long.parseLong(milliseconds);
```

Answer (score 2):

The server most probably returns `1383903835525` as `String`. Even if it's not `String`, it is a legal `long` value.

However, when you write a number literal in your code, it is always assumed as `int`, hence the "int is too long" error. Thus, you have to explicitly declare the number as `long` by appending `L`. (i.e. `1383903835525L`)

Comment: How would I go about appending this L?

Comment: I still couldn't understand what do you want to achieve. If you want to declare a `long` number in your code, then you need to append `L`. But if you receive/get a `long` value (e.g from parsing a `String`), then you don't need to append `L` at all and you can just use directly.